# Drawing an arc in java script but it doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometric-arc

I'm working on a simple html/js project to get a box moving in a canvas that can shoot a ball. I got the box moving but I cant get the ball to appear. The program makes it to the drawBall() and moveBall()(Tested using alerts) functions but they don't do anything. I've been working on this the past hour and so and I just can't get it to work. Here's my javascript code that moves the box and should draw a ball whenever the spacebar is released.

```
function init() {
//canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
WIDTH = $('#canvas').width();
HEIGHT = $('#canvas').height();
block_x = WIDTH / 2;
block_y = HEIGHT / 2;
setInterval('draw()', 25);
}

function clearCanvas() {
  context.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}

function draw() {
  clearCanvas();
  if(shotBall)
  {
        drawBall();
        moveBall();
  }
  if (rightKey) block_x += 5;
  else if (leftKey) block_x -= 5;
  if (upKey) block_y -= 5;
  else if (downKey) block_y += 5;
  if (block_x <= 0) block_x = 0;
  if ((block_x + block_w) >= WIDTH) block_x = WIDTH - block_w;
  if (block_y <= 0) block_y = 0;
  if ((block_y + block_h) >= HEIGHT) block_y = HEIGHT - block_h;
  context.fillRect(block_x, block_y, block_w, block_h);
 }

function drawBall() {
         context.beginPath();
     context.arc(ball_x, ball_y, ball_radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
}

function moveBall() {
    ball_y += 1;
    ball_x -= 1;
}

function onKeyDown(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 68) rightKey = true;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 65) leftKey = true;
  if (evt.keyCode == 87) upKey = true;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 83) downKey = true;
}

function onKeyUp(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 68) rightKey = false;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 65) leftKey = false;
  if (evt.keyCode == 87) upKey = false;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 83) downKey = false;
  if(evt.keyCode == 32) createBall();
}

function createBall() 
{
        ball_x = block_x + (block_w / 2); 
        ball_y = block_y + (block_y / 2);
    radius = 20;
    shotBall = true;
}
$(document).keydown(onKeyDown);
$(document).keyup(onKeyUp);
```

Comment: I use adobe Dreamweaver to write the code so it doesn't give me a error. Well no syntax errors at least, it checks for those. Unless there is a way to look at errors on Dreamweaver that I don't know about. But ya there is no error just the absence of the arc being drawn.

Comment: Same results, no ball draws. I tried context.stroke(); / context.fill(); and a combination of both of them... And if I put in the context.endPath(); the rectangle stops drawing also. By the way thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried your code
the problem that I can see is that you haven't initialized the **block_w**, and **block_h** and the **ball_radius** variables, because these values are seems to be undefined as I see in firebug tool.

So you have to make sure that you have defined and initialized every variable that you use.
Also You have to make sure that you are calling every function that you have defined.

When I put values manually in the context.arc(23, 34, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, false); function
then it works fine for me.
So make sure you have defined and initialized every variable.

Comment: thanks! It works now. Although I was defining block_w and block_h above the first function and not in the init(). I don't know why I originally did that but with your advice it works now! :D Happy days!